# Should bounties be used as a "currency" to hand out "work assignments"?

Tags: discussion, bounty, homework

I recently came across a question with a bounty [Calculate average exchange rate for time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351200/django-calculate-average-exchange-rate-for-time-period?noredirect=1#comment52793949_32351200) where the person asking the question set the rules for the reward description in such a way that he basically wanted someone to deliver for him 2 specific Postgre functions and  a Django model in order to earn the bounty.

> Reward is for the person who will write two PostgreSQL functions and
>   one Django class:
>
> months_between(date1, date2) - from link above without ABS
>   average_weight(value, start_date, end_date, range_start_date,
>   range_end_date) - implementing formula I've provided. AverageWeight -
>   Django custom class allowing to use in annotation in QuerySet: Own
>   aggregate functions Both PL/SQL functions are need to have ability to
>   use in SELECT statements.

The rules on this reward strike me as being closer to a set of requirements on a project than a set of requirements for a question to be considered as clearly answered. I attempted to answer what I thought was the question underlying the issue, and the responses I got from the person asking the question felt a lot like having a boss dictate what needed to get done on a project, more than a collaboration to answer a question.

My question is, should bounties be used to ask other people to basically "do my homework" by giving them a specific list of functions and requirements for inputs and outputs and constraints?Or is this the wrong way to use a bounty?

Comment: *Do my homework* kind of question are not really welcome on Stack Overflow even with a bounty on it. I guess it would attract people more interested in gaining rep than keeping high quality questions on the site though.

Comment: I'm perplexed by how the bounty was awarded. Actually, I'd say the currently accepted answer was plagiarized. The OP posted at the end of the question **"Please someone copy my accepted answer and post as own to receive reward."**. The OP had an answer that was deleted. The currently accepted answer looks to me like an unattributed copy of the OP's answer. (A note here: that the person whose answer was copied says "please copy my answer" does not entail it is not plagiarism. Plagiarism is not about a right to copy. It is about crediting ideas we use that are not our own.)

Comment: I'm way more concerned with the point @Louis is bringing up..... There's even a comment on the question by the guy who got the bounty saying "ok, I copied the accepted answer!"....

Comment: It is just a silly self-defeating way to spend a bounty.  In the end, SO users read it for what it was, a work assignment for fifty imaginary internet points.  So he didn't get any useful answers and had to solve it by himself.  We don't have to protect the OP from himself.

Comment: __I need to apologize SO community for my unclear behavior.  I know my actions were unclean__, but I need to choose winner and not one correct answer posted.. After 7 days I found solution and posted as own answer.. StackOverflow show me a warning that I need to choose a winner but not a one answer were good ( I coundn't choose my own answer).. I paniced..

Comment: @WBAR it's not a warning; there is no requirement to award the bounty to someone. The points are lost no matter what you do. You really should have read the help pages on bounties more closely; this is quite clear.

Comment: I looked at the question and thought,,, hmm. Strange, no Meta effect... 0 votes on both question and answers. Until I saw that it was actually +12/-12 on the question... I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without the portion explaining the "reward" rules, the question is actually all right.  It's well-stated, it's clear what was attempted (more or less a math exercise), and it's clear what they're interested in.

One shouldn't use the bounty system as a carrot to say, "If you give me this *exact* answer, then and only then will I reward you."  This is especially considering that if the community weighs in and the OP does not manually award the bounty, it'll go to the highest voted answer *anyway*.

This isn't a "do my homework" type question, since we have no indication that it's homework (or even related to schoolwork), and ultimately that doesn't matter.  The fact that the OP explicitly stated the kinds of functions that they want is unsettling, but again, without that part, the question is quite okay.

I would not encourage use of the bounty system to this effect.  You can't use a bounty as a bribe or payment to get someone to do your work for you.

Comment: "do my work" is even worse when it is paid work, than schoolwork

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Oh, absolutely.  I don't disagree there.  But I'm going to assume good faith on this one, as the question itself is, again, alright. If it were the case that the very explicit requirements were left off, would you also agree with that?

Comment: Listing the specific constraints he's working under is fine, but answers are supposed to get him past whatever has him stuck, not act as a code-writing service.  The explanation is more important than the code.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm getting at.  I'm no fan of the answer that won the bounty, but the question *without* the whole context spiel has a chance to be elaborated on and explained in great detail.

Comment: "I would not encourage use of the bounty system to this effect."  Agree.  Although I wouldn't formally _discourage_ such use either.  The person who creates a bounty is free to do so for any arbitrary reason they choose.  The automatic awarding of the bounty already effectively prevents them from enforcing arbitrary/capricious custom rules.  "You can't use a bounty as a bribe or payment to get someone to do your work for you."  Disagree.  In essence that's exactly what bounty is/does.   The only quibble here is over _how much control_ bounty gives you over that process.

Answer (score 19):

First, how the OP decides to award the bounty is entirely up to them.  Whether we know the criteria or not is immaterial to the problem.  They can use whatever system they want for determining the "winning" answer.

The question by itself wasn't a horrific failure until you get to the requirements part.  Before that it looks like a fairly well researched question, examples, data, all that good stuff.  And if it stopped there with a "so how do I fix this?" it would probably be ok (disclaimer: I know nothing of Django, so I can't speak to if all the posted code, etc. is enough to go on or not).

The "requirements" section causes the problem.  Now it turns from being a reasonably focused question into 3 more questions, all packaged up in one question and wrapped in a bounty.  Four questions in one.  Now the "too broad" bells are ringing.  Close it.  Burn it with fire.

As a note, specifically listing out your requirements for what you are looking for isn't necessarily a bad thing.  When it adds 3 new things that could each be their own question, now it's bad.

**TL/DR:** "Work assignments" are almost always too broad and should be closed as such.  Using a bounty to justify it or stave off closure is wholly inappropriate.

Comment: the original question was ok. I answered it and in the process got the chance to learn a few things. Up to that point it is a pretty good question and finding out what was causing the erroneous behaviour and how to fix it was all fine and dandy. 
I felt that it crossed a line on the bounty requirements because at that point it is no longer about the issue but rather about building a specific solution with very specific functions to solve the issue in a very particular way. It goes from "Im stuck with this, am I doing it right?" to I need you guys to build these functions for my specific case.

Comment: I would have expressed my disagreement with the way the question was written by not answering it, and if i felt compelled to leave at least some feedback, leave a comment, after downvoting. but then again i almost never look for bountied questions.