# Is there something wrong with promising bounties on my own question?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

I just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32978543/399649), which I'm very motivated to get answered quickly. The original version had the following at the bottom:

> ## This is the only thing blocking the release of this project, so I want to get it done ASAP. I'm going to be throwing a lot of bounties around.
>
> I'm going to put at least a 200 point bounty on this, maybe more. I'll
> award the full bounty to the answer that leads most directly to me
> solving my problem. I'll also award **bonus points** for all of the
> following:
>
> - Nothing but JavaScript and/or C#, and solve all of 1-4 above: 100pts
> - Don't make me do anything significant on the server besides the `Echo` handler: 50pts
> - Lowest possible time/effort/study on my end (e.g. a JS file I can drop into my project as-is, plus code I can simply cut & paste):
>   50-250pts, plus the 100 for covering parts 1-4. I don't mind learning
>   new things, but I want to get this done.
>
> All of these will be awarded even if there's no bounty at the time the
> answer is posted.

Within 2 minutes, this whole passage had been edited out by someone with 110K reputation (high enough to make me pause before reverting it). Did I break some kind of policy by adding this? Should I not have promised bounties in the question at all, or is it just that the 2-day waiting period wasn't up?

Comment: Questions should just contain questions.

Comment: There's a little box for that when actually posting the bounty. There's a character limit on it for a reason.

Comment: That's just noise and isn't needed in the question.

Comment: Not checking the question, but the way your block of extra text reads.... the question starts to look "too broad"  (checking question now... yeah a TAD broad, and with all those requirements, chances are it won't EVER be useful to ANYONE)

Comment: **ASAP** is just the biggest downvote attractor you could show anywhere here!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ other than "homework"

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not, if _homework is due tomorrow_.

Comment: @Patrice - Maybe I did a bad job of describing the issue then. The question is how to do backwards-compatible file I/O in a client-side SPA. It'll be useful to anyone who wants to do that, which seems pretty likely to me. Come to think of it, that's a much better question title.

Comment: @ryanyuyu In my experiences, "ASAP" correlates to a bad post much more strongly than "homework".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I figured the offer to make it rain would help with that, but maybe the ASAP ought to go.

Comment: @JustinMorgan It's actually a reflex of mine, when I'm seeing it here, almost no matter where.

Comment: You're getting pretty close to using SO as an outsourcing service, rather than a Q&A site, on that one.

Comment: [This seems...familiar...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305859/1079354)

Comment: 15K rep and still no basic idea of how SO works.  This is not good.  Where to begin...  You are doing it wrong.

Comment: duplicate question Should bounties be used as a “currency” to hand out “work assignments”?

Comment: @Makoto - That guy is asking for two functions and a class. I'm asking what's missing from a call to `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: @HansPassant - I think I just did a lousy job of asking my question, and I came off with a tone I wasn't trying to create. It's a very specific question about JavaScript file I/O in IE8, and I'm convinced that the underlying question is a good fit for SO. But having read these responses, I can see why people took it the way they did. I'm either going to edit the question or delete it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jonsharpe alluded to it in the comments, but I'll come right out and say it:

### You were trying to use bounties as bribes to outsource your work.

That's ***not*** cool.

---

[I'll leave the part about, "Is it okay to use the bounty system like this?" answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305860/1079354), since I don't want to repeat what's been said already, but we should take a look at the part that's left.

> All I need is some JS code (and potentially some C# to support it)
> that will do the following:
>
> 1. Given an XML string constructed on the client side, package the string into an XML file and save it to the user's machine.
> 2. Given a form with a `file`-type input, allow the user to upload the file from step 1 and load the file's contents into the JavaScript app.
> 3. Do all of the above without navigating away, and preferably without refreshing the page.
> 4. Preferably do all of this with JavaScript and the `Echo` handler, but some supporting C# is okay. I'd like to avoid
>    Flash/Silverlight/etc. if at all possible.

Instant trigger phrase:  **All I need is some ___ code**.  This also reads like an obligatory assignment; kind of like one would expect us to have this done by Friday at 11:59PM.

Honestly, the question would be alright if it left that part out.  Your timelines and requirements aren't our timelines or requirements, and we would hope that an answer provided at least gives you a lead with which to work from.

I respect that you've got deadlines to meet, but you shouldn't be relying on the masses here to help meet your deadline in this fashion.  It's fine to ask a question (or maybe several, since you've got some other requirements) about this, but you shouldn't also throw the [promise of a] bounty in as enticement.

Comment: I thought enticements were the whole point of bounties. I do get what you're saying, and I've seen plenty of the "do this for me" behavior you're talking about, but I honestly didn't think I was doing that. I had running code with a specific operation I was stuck on, I'd researched it and tried to solve it myself, and I had a specific question. I think I did a lousy job of asking it, and came across as a help vampire.

Comment: Having read the responses here, I can understand why my question left people with a bad taste. I'm really not trying to get people to do my work for me, or looking for more than two or three lines of code, but I made it sound that way. I'm either going to edit my question or delete it entirely.

Comment: @JustinMorgan:  That's probably what it was.  Your enticement wasn't really the sort of enticement I've personally come to expect from bounties.  I mean you no disrespect or anything like that, but the way you came across very much did seem help vampire-ish.

Comment: @JustinMorgan:  Actually, if all you do is remove the TL;DR, it would probably be okay.

Comment: I've now done that and more. I originally made my question sound much broader and lazier than it was, and I didn't make it clear what I'd already done to solve it. I definitely brought down the wrath of Meta on this one, but the feedback in here was actually really helpful.