# Is using bounty to pay for a small task acceptable?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've seen someone asking a question with a bounty.

Now:

- The person himself/herself has a high reputation (~30K).
- The person is capable of answering his/her own question (I'm pretty confident).

It seems like the person is using bounty as some sort of way to 'outsource' a task (writing a JavaScript script).

Is it ok, or misuse of the bounty program?

EDIT:

Upon further searching, it seems related to this:
*[Should bounties be used as a "currency" to hand out "work assignments"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305859/should-bounties-be-used-as-a-currency-to-hand-out-work-assignments)*

Comment: Is the question on-topic? If yes, there is nothing wrong with offering a bounty. And whether a user *"is capable of answering*" is a pretty big assumption to make.

Comment: It seems odd to me that a user would ask a narrowly-defined question they can answer themselves, not answer it, and then bounty it. Perhaps you're overestimating this user.

Comment: @adiga I agree that's normally it's a big assumption, but in this specific case - I'm confident since the user is asking for a ready-to-use script in a language he already provided answers for others.

Comment: @ErikA - could be. But at the moment I still think that he is more than capable.

Comment: @itsho but whether the OP knows about something is irrelevant and cannot be used to close a question. The focus should only be whether the Q & A is on-topic. But, I agree with the general theme of your question and how this can be misused. Bountied questions cannot be closed as *Too Broad*. Samuel has already answered how to address this bit.

Answer (score 7):

If a bountied question is too broad (or requires immediate deletion for some reason) please mod-flag it, we can refund the bounty and close the question.

The exceptions are:

- if the bounty is ending soon (e.g.: less than two days)
- if the question receives good answers while the bounty is active

then generally moderators may let the bounty expire normally since it has "paid its dues". In that case simply return to vote to close after the bounty has ended.

Comment: it's the opposite case - the question is really narrowed down to a very specific API which the user wants OTHER people to provide a working code for.

Comment: Oh interesting.. Can/should we only mod-flag for "too broad" close reason or can we do it also for blatant dupes, opinion based etc. questions?

Comment: Probably not dupes. Opinion-based sure.